# Want to show progess bar before launching an Activity

Tags: android, progress-bar

**I am using two activities: activity1 and activity2.In the first activity am using a button,after clicking on the button its should show the ProgessBar untill the activity2 is loaded completely.**

*We have to set visibility show and hide for the progress bar but m really confused between both the activites where to use those visibility criteria.Am stuck with this issue  and not able to solve this problem*

Can any one tell me the exact process to solve this issue.

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` and make `progress bar` invisible `onPostExecute(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by activity two is completely loaded? Are you doing any network operations in activity two? If not then you just need to start 2 through intent. 
 If some light operations are there you can do in on create and thereby updating UI for Activity2. 
 If some data needs to be made ready before loading activity2 then on your first activity button click do the following

- Initiate Async Task on activity 1 button click
- Do the operations in doInBackground method
- In onPostExecute get the data and start your activity2 through Intent object

Answer (score 0):

This is an unusual thing.

Can you elaborate what exact problem you are facing? or why you want to implement it?

1) if your activity is taking too long to load, you should show progress dialog before executing any code

**like**

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity{

    public void onCreate()
    {
    super.onCreate();

    //show progress dialog or progress 


    //other code here
    }
```

2) load images and other media or files or process data in AsyncTask

3) you can use multithreding using Threads and Runnables and distribute Tasks which take time to execute.